# Desktop will not load for specific user

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu.  Last time I played with it a bit was Jaunty.
Now I have just built a 14.04 Trusty File Server and added the Ubuntu Desktop to make some management tasks easier.

I was using the local desktop on the server successfully for several days.

I tried using XWindows the other day with my account with varied success.

Now when I go back to the Desktop ON the server, it won't let me login.

I can successfully login as another user and the desktop loads just fine.

But when I try to login as my account, the login screen dissapears like its trying to load the desktop, and then it comes back to the login screen  about 1-2 seconds later.

I went into CTRL+ALT+F1 and was able to login just fine.
I ran:

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo start lightdm
```

after reading another post on here, but no luck.

Any ideas?
Are there User specific X Windows files I can just go delete to perhaps put it back to how it was before?